SSRKeycloakProvider keeps adding the same auth to query on page reload
On my React-App authentication works alright but it keeps adding the auth at the of url as a new query on page reloads I couldn't figure it out why is it does that
So here my code as .tsx file any helps would be appreciated, thanks in advance
 return (
        <SSRKeycloakProvider
            keycloakConfig={keycloakConfig}
            persistor={SSRCookies(cookies)}
            initOptions={{
                checkLoginIframe: false,
                onLoad: 'login-required'
            }}
        >
            <StrictMode>
                <Provider store={store}>
                    <UserInfoController>
                        <LocalStorageSynchronizer>
                            <Waiter>
                                {pageProps.Layout == 'FullPage' ? (
                                    <FullPage>
                                        <Component {...pageProps} />
                                    </FullPage>
                                ) : (
                                    <Dashboard>
                                        {pageLoading ? (
                                            <div className="flex h-full">
                                                <Spinner className="m-auto" />
                                            </div>
                                        ) : (
                                            <Component {...pageProps} />
                                        )}
                                        <ToastContainer position="bottom-right" autoClose={3000} />
                                    </Dashboard>
                                )}
                            </Waiter>
                        </LocalStorageSynchronizer>
                    </UserInfoController>
                </Provider>
            </StrictMode>    
        </SSRKeycloakProvider>
    );

I tried to use <StrictMode> but it didn't help as well
